# How to get the extension degree

Tags: algebra

The real number field cannot express $\sqrt{2}$, so we extend $2$ times to get $Q(\sqrt{2})=a+b\sqrt(2)$. But it cannot express $\sqrt{3}$ still. So we are going to extend it $2$ more times to get $Q(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}+d\sqrt{6}$. Then we express it all now after extend  $4$ times.

Similarly, how to know **the minimum extension degree** from the field of real numbers to include

```
lis1 = {-(-2)^(1/3), 2^(1/3), (-1)^(2/3) 2^(1/3)}
```

or

```
lis2 = {-2,
        -(1/4) + (I Sqrt[3])/4 - 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) + (7 I Sqrt[3])/2],
        -(1/4) - (I Sqrt[3])/4 - 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) - (7 I Sqrt[3])/2],
        -(1/4) - (I Sqrt[3])/4 + 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) - (7 I Sqrt[3])/2],
        -(1/4) + (I Sqrt[3])/4 + 1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) + (7 I Sqrt[3])/2]}
```

by *MMA*?

Comment: Does [`ToNumberField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToNumberField) do what you want

Comment: @CarlWoll I can use it to get the minimum extension degree?

Comment: "ToNumberField[{Subscript[a, 1],Subscript[a, 2],\[Ellipsis]},All] always uses the smallest common field extension." — from the docs

Comment: @MichaelE2 So what is the extension degree of this field?

Comment: The degree of the polynomial?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The degree of the field that includes all number elements.

Comment: Doesn't it give you a `Root[]` object that is the primitive element? It has the degree in it, or you can extract it with `MinimalPolynomial[Root[...], x]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Wow, I realize you might be right. It may deserve an answer rather than just a comment

Comment: It was @Carl 's idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ToNumberField`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToNumberField) to do this:

```
extensionDegree[l_List] := Replace[ToNumberField[l, All],
    {
    {___, a_AlgebraicNumber, ___} :> Length @ Last @ a,
    _->Missing["NotAvailable"]
    }
]
```

Your examples:

```
extensionDegree[{Sqrt[2], Sqrt[3]}]
extensionDegree[{-(-2)^(1/3), 2^(1/3), (-1)^(2/3) 2^(1/3)}]
extensionDegree[{-2, -(1/4) + (I Sqrt[3])/4 -  1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) + (7 I Sqrt[3])/2], -(1/4) - (I Sqrt[3])/4 -  1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) - (7 I Sqrt[3])/2], -(1/4) - (I Sqrt[3])/4 +  1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) - (7 I Sqrt[3])/2], -(1/4) + (I Sqrt[3])/4 +  1/2 Sqrt[-(1/2) + (7 I Sqrt[3])/2]}]
```

> 4

> 6

> 8

Comment: It might be nice if it handled `extensionDegree[{3, 5/7}]`. So maybe a rule like `{(_Integer | _Rational) ...} :> 1` could be added to `Replace`.